# How to check whether xcodebuild succeeded in the post-action shell?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, shell, xcodebuild

Is there any way to check if `xcodebuild` is successful in the `post-action` shell?
I want to run a custom script only when the build succeeds.

I checked env vars with the `set` command in the `post-action` shell, but couldn't find a suitable var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode's post-action script, you don't have direct access to the exit status of the xcodebuild command.

I not sure about this but you can check the existence of the generated build for example your app bundle. To infer whether the build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `post-action` of `Archive` action. It's called only if build was successful